# How to read a hexadecimal file and convert the content to byte slice in golang?

Tags: go

The hexadecimal file is from the charles proxy's hex format, and it may contains invisible characters, the example format content is:

```
00000000  7b 22 73 75 70 70 6f 72 74 73 5f 69 6d 70 6c 69   {"supports_impli
00000010  63 69 74 5f 73 64 6b 5f 6c 6f 67 67 69 6e 67 22   cit_sdk_logging"
00000020  3a 74 72 75 65 2c 22 67 64 70 76 34 5f 6e 75 78   :true,"gdpv4_nux
00000030  5f 65 6e 61 62 6c 65 64 22 3a 66 61 6c 73 65 2c   _enabled":false,
00000040  22 61 6e 64 72 6f 69 64 5f 73 64 6b 5f 65 72 72   "android_sdk_err
00000050  6f 72 5f 63 61 74 65 67 6f 72 69 65 73 22 3a 5b   or_categories":[
00000060  7b 22 6e 61 6d 65 22 3a 22 6c 6f 67 69 6e 5f 72   {"name":"login_r
00000070  65 63 6f 76 65 72 61 62 6c 65 22 2c 22 69 74 65   ecoverable","ite
00000080  6d 73 22 3a 5b 7b 22 63 6f 64 65 22 3a 31 30 32   ms":[{"code":102
00000090  7d 2c 7b 22 63 6f 64 65 22 3a 31 39 30 7d 5d 2c   },{"code":190}],
000000a0  22 72 65 63 6f 76 65 72 79 5f 6d 65 73 73 61 67   "recovery_messag
000000b0  65 22 3a 22 5c 75 38 62 66 37 5c 75 39 31 63 64   e":"\u8bf7\u91cd
000000c0  5c 75 36 35 62 30 5c 75 37 36 37 62 5c 75 35 66   \u65b0\u767b\u5f
000000d0  35 35 5c 75 35 65 39 34 5c 75 37 35 32 38 5c 75   55\u5e94\u7528\u
000000e0  37 61 30 62 5c 75 35 65 38 66 5c 75 66 66 30 63   7a0b\u5e8f\uff0c
000000f0  5c 75 35 31 38 64 5c 75 36 62 32 31 5c 75 38 66   \u518d\u6b21\u8f
00000100  64 65 5c 75 36 33 61 35 20 46 61 63 65 62 6f 6f   de\u63a5 Faceboo
00000110  6b 20 5c 75 35 65 31 30 5c 75 36 32 33 37 5c 75   k \u5e10\u6237\u
00000120  33 30 30 32 22 7d 5d 2c 22 61 70 70 5f 65 76 65   3002"}],"app_eve
00000130  6e 74 73 5f 73 65 73 73 69 6f 6e 5f 74 69 6d 65   nts_session_time
00000140  6f 75 74 22 3a 36 30 2c 22 61 70 70 5f 65 76 65   out":60,"app_eve
00000150  6e 74 73 5f 66 65 61 74 75 72 65 5f 62 69 74 6d   nts_feature_bitm
00000160  61 73 6b 22 3a 36 35 35 35 39 2c 22 73 65 61 6d   ask":65559,"seam
00000170  6c 65 73 73 5f 6c 6f 67 69 6e 22 3a 31 2c 22 73   less_login":1,"s
00000180  6d 61 72 74 5f 6c 6f 67 69 6e 5f 62 6f 6f 6b 6d   mart_login_bookm
00000190  61 72 6b 5f 69 63 6f 6e 5f 75 72 6c 22 3a 22 68   ark_icon_url":"h
000001a0  74 74 70 73 3a 5c 2f 5c 2f 73 74 61 74 69 63 2e   ttps:\/\/static.
000001b0  78 78 2e 66 62 63 64 6e 2e 6e 65 74 5c 2f 72 73   xx.fbcdn.net\/rs
000001c0  72 63 2e 70 68 70 5c 2f 76 33 5c 2f 79 73 5c 2f   rc.php\/v3\/ys\/
000001d0  72 5c 2f 43 36 5a 75 74 59 44 53 61 61 56 2e 70   r\/C6ZutYDSaaV.p
000001e0  6e 67 22 2c 22 73 6d 61 72 74 5f 6c 6f 67 69 6e   ng","smart_login
000001f0  5f 6d 65 6e 75 5f 69 63 6f 6e 5f 75 72 6c 22 3a   _menu_icon_url":
00000200  22 68 74 74 70 73 3a 5c 2f 5c 2f 73 74 61 74 69   "https:\/\/stati
00000210  63 2e 78 78 2e 66 62 63 64 6e 2e 6e 65 74 5c 2f   c.xx.fbcdn.net\/
00000220  72 73 72 63 2e 70 68 70 5c 2f 76 33 5c 2f 79 73   rsrc.php\/v3\/ys
00000230  5c 2f 72 5c 2f 30 69 61 72 70 6e 77 64 6d 45 78   \/r\/0iarpnwdmEx
00000240  2e 70 6e 67 22 2c 22 72 65 73 74 72 69 63 74 69   .png","restricti
00000250  76 65 5f 64 61 74 61 5f 66 69 6c 74 65 72 5f 70   ve_data_filter_p
00000260  61 72 61 6d 73 22 3a 22 7b 7d 22 2c 22 61 61 6d   arams":"{}","aam
00000270  5f 72 75 6c 65 73 22 3a 22 7b 7d 22 2c 22 73 75   _rules":"{}","su
00000280  67 67 65 73 74 65 64 5f 65 76 65 6e 74 73 5f 73   ggested_events_s
00000290  65 74 74 69 6e 67 22 3a 22 7b 5c 22 70 72 6f 64   etting":"{\"prod
000002a0  75 63 74 69 6f 6e 5f 65 76 65 6e 74 73 5c 22 3a   uction_events\":
000002b0  5b 5d 2c 5c 22 65 6c 69 67 69 62 6c 65 5f 66 6f   [],\"eligible_fo
000002c0  72 5f 70 72 65 64 69 63 74 69 6f 6e 5f 65 76 65   r_prediction_eve
000002d0  6e 74 73 5c 22 3a 5b 5c 22 66 62 5f 6d 6f 62 69   nts\":[\"fb_mobi
000002e0  6c 65 5f 61 64 64 5f 74 6f 5f 63 61 72 74 5c 22   le_add_to_cart\"
000002f0  2c 5c 22 66 62 5f 6d 6f 62 69 6c 65 5f 70 75 72   ,\"fb_mobile_pur
00000300  63 68 61 73 65 5c 22 2c 5c 22 66 62 5f 6d 6f 62   chase\",\"fb_mob
00000310  69 6c 65 5f 63 6f 6d 70 6c 65 74 65 5f 72 65 67   ile_complete_reg
00000320  69 73 74 72 61 74 69 6f 6e 5c 22 2c 5c 22 66 62   istration\",\"fb
00000330  5f 6d 6f 62 69 6c 65 5f 69 6e 69 74 69 61 74 65   _mobile_initiate
00000340  64 5f 63 68 65 63 6b 6f 75 74 5c 22 5d 7d 22 2c   d_checkout\"]}",
00000350  22 69 64 22 3a 22 31 36 33 35 34 33 35 31 34 39   "id":"1635435149
00000360  30 39 30 34 35 22 7d                              09045"}
```

Read the file and convert the hexadecimal content to golang slice []byte, is there any convenient method? how to split the lines in the file?

Comment: What did you try, what didn't go well.

Comment: Thi may help you https://golang.org/src/encoding/hex/example_test.go

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by using fixed length of the hexadecimal content. the offset length of each line is 8, so the hexadecimal content begins at offset 8, and the max length of the hexadecimal is 57. The code is as follows:

```
const (
    beginOffset = 8 // the offset of the hexadecimal content begins
    endLength = 57  // the length of the hexadecimal content ends
)

func ReadHexData(src []byte) ([]byte, error) {

    lines := strings.Split(string(src), "\n")

    var data string
    for _, line := range lines {
        for i := beginOffset; i < endLength; i++ {
            if line[i] != ' ' {
                data = data + string(line[i])
            }
        }
    }

    return hex.DecodeString(data)
}
```